# Не находит файл в VS 17

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <math.h> 
#include <iostream> 
int main() {
    float A[16];
    int i, limit;
    do {
        printf("Введите количество элементов (не более 16)");
        scanf("%d", &limit);
        if (limit > 1 && limit < 17) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            printf("Введите количество элементов (не более 16)");
        }
    } while (1);

    return 0;
}
```

Вот сам код. После сборки выводит "Не удается загрузить программу" (exe)

> ------ Сборка начата: проект: Project8, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
>   Source.cpp
>   c:\users\user\source\repos\project8\project8\source.cpp(12): error C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
>   c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0 \ucrt\stdio.h(1274): note:  см. объявление "scanf"
>   c:\users\user\source\repos\project8\project8\source.cpp(9): warning C4101: i: неиспользованная локальная переменная
>   c:\users\user\source\repos\project8\project8\source.cpp(8): warning C4101: A: неиспользованная локальная переменная
>   Сборка проекта "Project8.vcxproj" завершена с ошибкой.
>   ========== Сборка: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========

Он просто не сохраняет файл. Если в этот же файл добавить другой код, то он работает прекрасно.

В онлайн компиляторе все работает. В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, у вас в настройках трактовать предупреждения как ошибки.

Ну так исправьте код - используйте `scanf_s("%d", &limit);`, которую он просит, или добавьте самой первой строкой кода

```
#define  _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS  1
```

Компилятор, как мне кажется, очень внятно не только сказал о своих претензиях, но и о том, как их удовлетворить:

**Consider using scanf_s instead**

или

**use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS**

И еще - из-за этого

```
else {
    printf("Введите количество элементов (не более 16)");
}
```

Вы будете получать два запроса на повторный ввод в случае ошибки..

Еще два предупреждения пропадут, когда вы допишете свой код и будете использовать неиспользуемые ныне (но объявленные) переменные.